# Non-snc locus relative to a smooth morphism

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, dg.differential-geometry, complex-geometry, smooth-manifolds, hodge-theory

Let $f\colon X\rightarrow Y$ be a smooth morphism between smooth varieties and $B\subset Y$ a simple normal crossing divisor such that $f^*(B)$ is simple normal crossing as well. Consider a semiample divisor $H$ on $X$ (you may assume ample, or very ample) and a general element $H'\in |H|$ in its linear system.

Even if $H'$ is general, the divisor $H'+f^*(B)$ may not be relatively simple normal crossing with respect to  $f$. Lets define ${\rm Non-snc}_f(H'+f^*(B))$ to be the maximal subvariety $Z\subset Y$ such that $H'+f^*(B)$ is relatively snc over $Y\setminus Z$.

1. Is $N={\rm Non-snc}_f(H'+f^*(B))$ a divisor?
2. If yes, does $N+B$ have simple normal crossing support?

What if $B$ is trivial?

Comment: Are you requiring $f^*(B)$ to be reduced?

Comment: You can assume that, or replace the snc hypothesis with snc support.